# How to show a loading spinner while waiting on an observable getting data from a service in Angular

Tags: angular

I have set up an observable service that helps me persist data, but I need a way to show a loading spinner while the data is waiting to come from the observable.

My service:

```
imports [...]

import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrganisationsService {
  private organisations$ = new BehaviorSubject<Organisation[]>([
    {
      [...]
    }
  ]);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http
      .get(
        environment.apicall
      )
      .subscribe((data) => this.organisations$.next(data['organisations']));
  }

  getList(): Observable<Organisation[]> {
    return this.organisations$.asObservable();
  }
```

Here's my component:

```
    imports ...

    import UIkit from 'uikit';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-organisationlist',
      templateUrl: './organisationlist.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./organisationlist.component.css']
    })
    export class OrganisationlistComponent implements OnInit {

      public loading = true;

      public organisations$: Observable<Organisation[]>;

      constructor(public organisationsService: OrganisationsService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getData().then(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        });
      }

      async getData() {
        this.organisations$ = this.organisationsService.getList();
      }
}
```

Here's my layout (uses Uikit):

```
  <div *ngIf="loading" uk-spinner></div>
  <div>
    <ul class="uk-list">
      <li *ngFor="let organisation of organisations$ | async">
        {{ organisation.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Obviously, the `getData` function, although declared async, is not actually async and returns immediately. So `this.loading` is 'false' OnInit, and therefore it doesn't show.

There are plenty of answers around that show how this might work when the subscription happens in the component, but because this is shared data in a service, I can't find a way to wait on the data before setting `this.loading` to false.

Many thanks.

Comment: the best: https://nils-mehlhorn.de/posts/indicating-loading-the-right-way-in-angular

Comment: Thanks Eliseo... for some reason `else indicator` with `ng-template` wouldn't work for me.

Comment: I complementary the comment with an answer and an example, I hope this can help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use <mat-progress-bar> in .ts while calling the API service using angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855216/how-to-use-mat-progress-bar-in-ts-while-calling-the-api-service-using-angular)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses, but none of these suggestions worked for the purposes outlined in the question, but I did work on a solution and eventually got one working. Here we go:

In the service I created a new Observable called `loading$` and set it up as a `new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);`

Then I created a getter:

`getLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loading$;
  }`

Then I wrapped the HTTP call with a `true` then set loading to `false` in the 3rd argument on the subscription (the [onCompleted](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) function).

So the service looks like this:

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrganisationsService {
  private organisations$ = new BehaviorSubject<Organisation[]>([
    {
      [...]
    }
  ]);

  //initiate the new Loading variable via BehaviorSubject and set it to "true" from the beginning.
  public loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    //set the loading$ to true again just before we start the HTTP call
    this.loading$.next(true);


    this.http
      .get(environment.apicall)
      .subscribe(

        //onNext method, where we get the data
        (data) => this.organisations$.next(data['organisations']),

        //onError method (Blank for now)
        () => {},

        //onComplated method, now that we have the data we can set the loading to false
        () => {
          this.loading$.next(false);
        }
      );
  }

  getLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loading$;
  }

  getList(): Observable<Organisation[]> {
    return this.organisations$;
  }
```

Notice in the subscribe method on the HTTP call, I'm adding a blank second method (This is for onError) and then in the 3rd method, I've added a function to set the loading to false: `this.loading$.next(false);` . This means that Loading will now be false when the subscription is complete.

Then in my component, I get the `loading$` subscription:

```
      public loading$: Observable<boolean>;
      public organisations$: Observable<Organisation[]>;

      constructor(public organisationsService: OrganisationsService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getData();
      }

      async getData() {

        //initially loading$ will be true because the service makes it so
        this.loading$ = this.organisationsService.getLoading();

        //when this completes, loading$ will be set to false via the service
        this.organisations$ = this.organisationsService.getList();
      }
```

And in my view:

```
  <div>
    <div uk-spinner *ngIf="loading$ | async"></div>
    <ul class="uk-list">
      <li *ngFor="let organisation of organisations$ | async">
        {{ organisation.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: The "onCompleted()" callback only fires after the "onSuccess()" has completed. It does not fire after the "onError()" callback, so you might consider using a pipe containing a "finalize()" operator to emit the loading$ there.

Answer (score 1):

You can create own service that included behavior subject and public loading function. (app.service.ts)

```
public loading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
public isLoading(state: boolean): void { this.loading.next(state) }
```

And in your app.component.ts. Inject the AppService in constructor so can be observed:

```
public loading$ = this.appService.loading.asObservable()
```

In app.component.html view, import the shared spinner as below:

```
<spinner [showSpinner]="loading$ | async"></spinner>
```

> The shared component @input showSpinner with *ngIf flag to decide
> to show the spinner or not.

At final, in the your return api calling can write something like:

```
this.appService.isLoading(true)
return this.callApiByMethod(options).pipe(
  finalize(() => this.appService.isLoading(false)),
  shareReplay(),
) as Observable<T>
```

I use rx finalize here so it will create a callback function that can handle with both success and error response.

Answer (score 0):

You can more changes in `OrganisationlistComponent`

```
 export class OrganisationlistComponent implements OnInit {

      public loading = false; // Default false 

      public organisations$: Observable<Organisation[]>;

      constructor(public organisationsService: OrganisationsService) {}

      ngOnInit() {

        this.getData().then((data) => {
        this.organisations$ = data; 
        this.loading = false; //  false one response
        });
      }

     async getData() {
        this.loading = true //  true whene loading data;
        return  this.organisationsService.getList();  // return data
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vijay. But this doesn't work either... because getData is returning immediately, then the `then` block in returning immediately, so `this.loading` is false immediately.

Answer (score 0):

change the below line

```
async getData() {
    this.organisations$ = this.organisationsService.getList();
  }
```

to

```
async getData() {
   this.organisations$ = this.organisationsService.getList();
   this.organisations$.subscribe((data) => 
     this.loading = false;
   );
  }
```

this should work because this is the observable you are waiting for completion, not the getData method

Comment: Thank you Vilsad, But this doesn't work either... again, `getData` is returning immediately, and therefore `this.loading` is immediately false.

Answer (score 0):

Complementary my comment using the [nils' operator](https://nils-mehlhorn.de/posts/indicating-loading-the-right-way-in-angular). I like this solution because is "transparent", see that a call is simply,e.g.

```
return this.httpClient.get('.....').pipe(
      indicate(this.loading$))
```

Moreover, You can use with any observable, not only call http. Using rxjs operators for, e.g. make severals http call using forkJoin, or use switchMap to make two calls you has only a pipe, don't overload the calls and don't cause a flick

The operator as

```
export const prepare = <T>(callback: () => void) => {
    return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> =>
        defer(() => {
            callback();
            return source;
        });
};

export const indicate = <T>(indicator: Subject<boolean>) => {
    let alive = true;
    return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> =>
        source.pipe(
            prepare(() =>
                timer(500)
                    .pipe(
                        takeWhile(() => alive),
                        take(1)
                    )
                    .subscribe(() => {
                        indicator.next(true);
                    })
            ),
            finalize(() => {
                alive = false;
                indicator.next(false);
            })
        );
};

export const toClass = <T>(ClassType: { new(): T }) => (
    source: Observable<T>
) => source.pipe(map(val => Object.assign(new ClassType(), val)));
```

I put a timer because I don't want the "loading" is showed if the call not spend more than 500 miliseconds

A service like

```
export class DataService {

  loading$ = new Subject<boolean>()


  getData():Observable<any>
  {
    //one call, I simulate a simple response
    //in general will be like this.httpClient.get(....)
    const observable=of('New Data in'+new Date()).pipe(delay(1000))

    return observable.pipe(
      indicate(this.loading$))
  }
}
```

I has, e.g. in our app.component

```
<button (click)="loadData()">load</button>
{{data}}
<div *ngIf="(dataService.loading$ | async)">
    loading...
</div>
```

And the function loadData

```
export class AppComponent  {
  data:any
  //don't forget declare as public
  constructor(public dataService:DataService){}
  loadData()
  {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res=>{
      this.data=res
    })
  }
}
```

**Update**
Well, I make that $loading belongs to the service, but you can make that $loading belongs to the component and use the pipe in the component

```
  loading$ = new Subject<boolean>()
  loadData2()
  {
    this.data="";
    this.dataService.getData2().pipe(
      indicate(this.loading$))
      .subscribe(res=>{
      this.data=res
    })
  }

<div *ngIf="(loading$ | async)">
    loading...
</div>
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ycxxgm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)