# angular - show loading while rxjs subscription waits for data

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple subscription inside my onInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.monitoringService.getHeartbeats())
      ).subscribe(data => this.heartbeats = data.data);
}
```

but i'd like to show a simple loading bar, while the subscription gets data from the server. Is there any way to set a variable like `this.loading` to `true` at start and `false` when the data is fetched?

For completness, this is an example of heartbeats i get:

```
....
  {
    _id: 5e58595325c28e4470c90d45,
    customer: 5cab35ae9a39025a6b8cef7e,
    activeUsers: 11,
    usersLoggedIn: 7,
    terminals: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    heartbeatDate: 2020-02-28T00:05:39.277Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5e58593a25c28e4470c90d42,
    customer: 5cab35ae9a39025a6b8cef7e,
    activeUsers: 11,
    usersLoggedIn: 7,
    terminals: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    heartbeatDate: 2020-02-28T00:05:14.311Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5e5858aac78f000c70ac2468,
    customer: 5cab35ae9a39025a6b8cef7e,
    activeUsers: 11,
    usersLoggedIn: 7,
    terminals: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    heartbeatDate: 2020-02-28T00:02:50.575Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5e5858348b2d6d3d0c1d482e,
    customer: 5cab35ae9a39025a6b8cef7e,
    activeUsers: 11,
    usersLoggedIn: 7,
    terminals: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    heartbeatDate: 2020-02-28T00:00:52.306Z,
    __v: 0
  } 
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 5000).pipe(
        tap(() => this.loading = true),
        switchMap(() => this.monitoringService.getHeartbeats())
      ).subscribe(data => { 
                           this.heartbeats = data.data; 
                           this.loading = false;
       }, err => this.loading = false ); // handle error how you want, just turn loading off as well
}
```

Comment: the loading should be triggerd every time the subscription is called. This is given with your example?

Comment: No, before it was just the first time. I have edited for every time using the `tap` operator. Check it out. Sorry about that.

Comment: Another aproach using a operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078

Comment: When unsubscribing before loading is done this will remain in `loading` true state. You could use the `finalize` pipe for solving that, it will work on complete, error and cancel/unsubscribe.

Comment: when working with Http calls, tap() will not be called if source observable emits an error.