# Stop loading in subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactivex

What would be the best way if I have to top a loading.
I have the following.

```
loadProducts() {
    this.subscription = this._productService.getAll()
      .subscribe(products => {
        this.isLoading = false
        this.products = products;
      },
        () => this.isLoading = false,
        () => this.isLoading = false
      );
  }
```

this.isLoading = false in "next", "error" and "complete" Obviously it is to ensure that loading stops even when there is an error.
There's a way to reduce this, let's say, something like attaching a callback or lambda to the subscribe and having it run in all cases

Comment: you ask about the best way, **for me** is using an operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078, and using another more complex in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769941/ionic-4-correct-way-to-show-loading-no-records-and-data-block/60770597#60770597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice is to use RxJS operators for this case like `finalize` or `tap` and `catchError`:

```
loadProducts() {
    this.subscription = this._productService.getAll()
      .pipe(
          finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)),
          catchError(error => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            return throwError(error);
          })
        )
      .subscribe(products => this.products = products);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma619245726433166?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

You could do something like:

```js
_cancel$ = new Subject<void>();

loadProducts() {
  this.subscription = this._productService.getAll()
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._cancel$))
    .subscribe(products => (this.products = products),
    () => this.isLoading = false,
    () => this.isLoading = false
  );
}
```

You can do this, for example:

```html
<button (click)="loadProducts()">Load Products</button>
<button (click)="_cancel$.next()">Cancel Loading Products</button>
```

When `_cancel$` emits, the ongoing subscription will be canceled as a consequence of the `takeUntil` operator (it cancels the subscription when the observable passed as a parameter to it emits - complete function still runs).

There's no need to set `isLoading` to false in the subscriber function because you're already doing it on the error function and on the complete function.