# Manage loader/spinner for multiple simultaneous async service calls using Angular HTTP interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have implemented Http Interceptor and showing spinner when service is initiated and hiding spinner when service is success/fails.

Code Sample:

```
        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

             return next.handle(req).pipe(
                tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.body.errCode != undefined) {
                        // show_spinner

                    }
                }),
                finalize(()=>{
                    // hide_spinner
             })
         }
```

For example there are two service calls both occurs at same time; therefore spinner will be shown corresponding to both calls but first service is finished in **2 secs** and second in **5 secs**; Now spinner will be hidden after the first call is finished, will not be able to acknowledge second service call.

Comment: I suggest use an operator, not a Http Interceptor, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078, else you need has a count

Comment: Increment and decrement a count of inflight calls, and show the spinner if it's > 0?

Comment: Has you see the SO? The operator is apply to a subscription -not to the call-. This allow use in a forkJoin, or switchMap, so you has no "concurrents" calls

Comment: Much appreciable @Eliseo my aim is to not avoid calls concurrency as these calls are asynchronous; they may occur at almost same time but to find a logic to acknowledge each service call.

Comment: I thought that your aim was show a spinner when a call is done, I personally I think that the idea of create an operator it's the best solution, but it's only a personal opinion

Comment: @jonrsharpe unable to maintain a count properly, can you suggest when to initialize count variable? Count initialization is bugging me!

Comment: Surely it's just set to `0` when the interceptor is constructed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question, so one can refer to the solution to above question/problem.

Firstly, declare a global variable (initialize it as 0) used as a counter for active service calls.

Secondly, for each service intercepted increment count(counter variable) and when service call is finalize decrement the count(counter variable).

Lastly, if service count is equal to zero hide the spinner else show the spinner.

Example:
Define an interceptor service in general for intercepting HTTP Requests.After that
in interceptor service :

```
service_count = 0; // initialize the counter.

constructor(
    private _route:Router
) {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  this.service_count++; // increment the count for each intercepted http request.
  // show spinner.

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    this.service_count--;
                 // decrement when service is completed (success/failed both 
                    handled when finalize rxjs operator used)

                    if (this.service_count === 0) {
                        // hide spinner
                    }
                })
            );
}
```

Comment: I keep learning this part because with your suggest mi forkjoin now is workning like single calls, l would like to print what request is processing, what failed or what finished with no probles is for debug purpouses