# How to stop loader/spinner until all http response complete in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have created a loaderInterceptor to show/hide the spinner.
I have a page where multiple HTTP calls are going to get data from APIs, during calls, I show the spinner, and on HTTP request call completion hide the spinner.

**Problem:** Between multiple Http call spinner, not working as expected means found some flickering problem in spinner(show/hide ......n).

My requirement is how to show spinner when the first HTTP call made and hide spinner when all HTTP call completed.

This is my Loader Interceptor code.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyLoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private requests = 0;
    removeloaderTime: any;

    constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }
    private stop = ((req: any): void => {
        this.removeloaderTime = setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.requests > 0) {
                this.requests--;
            }

            if (this.requests === 0) {
                // Hide Loader
                // loaderService.hide()
                clearTimeout(this.removeloaderTime);
            }
        }, 2000);
    })

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.requests++
        // Show Loader
        // loaderService.show()
        return new Observable(observer => {
            const subscription = next.handle(req)
                .subscribe(
                    event => {
                        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                            this.stop(req);
                            observer.next(event);
                        }
                    },
                    err => {
                        this.stop(req);
                        observer.error(err);
                    },
                    () => {
                        this.stop(req);
                        observer.complete();
                    });
            return () => {
                this.stop(req);
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `loaderService` looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {
  constructor() {}

  isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();
  show() {
    this.isLoading.next(true);
  }
  hide() {
    this.isLoading.next(false);
  }
}
```

Then, I suggest you to create an interceptor called `LoadingService` like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoadingService } from '../utils/loading.service';
@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public loaderService: LoadingService) {}
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loaderService.show();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => this.loaderService.hide()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this solution and my solution which I have mentioned in the code above have some flickering (show and hide ...) loader issue for multiple HTTP requests. this is working fine for a single Http request but not for multiple Http request

Comment: I believe finalize() handles multiple http requests, but it won't work if you convert Observables to Promises.

Comment: You can check this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847647/manage-loader-spinner-for-multiple-simultaneous-async-service-calls-using-angula

Comment: I have also used the same code but it is not working for multiple requests simultaneously. because the result of show/hide are (true,false,false,true,false,false). it should be n true and n false. is there any way to know how many requests made then we can show the loader on fisrt request and hide the loader on last request.

Comment: Would you provide more information about your components, services, etc., and how you call multiple web services? Please add them in your question.