# Capture cancelled/abort request on HttpInterceptor. Angular8

Tags: angular, http

I'm having a problem in an application built with Angular 8.

I have an application-level spinner that turns on for every http request made and turns off in responses.

These requests are captured by an HttpInterceptor that shows a load spinner and when the response is obtained it is hidden. 
The problem comes when some of these http calls are cancelled, as in this example:

```
  search(param: string) {
    return terms.debounceTime(SEARCH_DEBOUNCE)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.search(param));
  }
```

The above code belongs to a text search engine where when you stop typing for a period of time the search is performed. When this is done too quickly, several requests can be made simultaneously, which switchMap then cancels.
For this reason, when the requests are cancelled, the interceptor is not able to get the status of that cancellation and therefore the spinner never disappears.

The interceptor does something like this:

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    // the spinner is shown

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        // error handling and spinner stop
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        // Access to all responses except cancelled requests, which have no response.
      })
    );
```

Therefore for those cases where the request is cancelled or aborted, I cannot stop the spinner.

Comment: It's not a response, but if you use a operator to show a loading instead a interceptor you solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to stop the spinner without any specific condition, but just in the return statement, you can use the tap operator (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) like this:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
// the spinner is shown

return next.handle(request).pipe(
  catchError(error => {

    // Do things
  }),
  finalize(() => {
   // Do things
  }),
  tap(()=> /* stop spinning */)
);
```

Comment: You might also want to use a reference counter so that each start request increments the counter and each stop request decrements the counter. this way you can have the spinner visible from a central location and correctly stop even if you have parallel requests running

Comment: @Riccardo you're right, but it's important to remark the difference between tap() and finalize() operators. The first one can be used to stop the spinner as you stated, but it will not be fired if the request is cancelled. On the other hand, finalize() operator will be fired even if the request is cancelled.