# Get spinner/progress bar on component level by intercepting http req in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a requirement where I need to display spinner (or) progress bar on component level. Each of these components call different end-points.

I followed few approaches suggested below but they intercept all the http-requests. How to go about intercepting these requests on component level and display spinners?

*https://medium.com/@deniscangemi/intercept-http-requests-in-angular-c6392b7b0e0*

*https://medium.com/@zeljkoradic/loader-bar-on-every-http-request-in-angular-6-60d8572a21a9*

Comment: you can't do this with HttpClient

Comment: If you want to make animation without progress bar is possible

Comment: create a component example where you want to intercept this

Comment: I agree with @Chris, a code sample would help out a lot with answers

Comment: my best bet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078

Answer (score 0):

If you are going the Http interceptor route, then you can just take advantage of using either an [event emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) and then listen for messages related to the call you are checking for.  Another thing you can do would be to have a [service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) that you set in the interceptor, but also you can listen for you the component.