# Angular - How to properly implement loading interceptor

Tags: angular

I would like to have a loading component that I could use in my different components to display spinner. I already have a loading interceptor and the loading service, as well as the loading component itself.

```
export class LoadingInterceptor {
  private activeRequests = 0;

  constructor(private loadingScreenService: LoadingService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.activeRequests === 0) {
      this.loadingScreenService.startLoading();
    }

    this.activeRequests++;

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.activeRequests--;
        if (this.activeRequests === 0) {
          this.loadingScreenService.stopLoading();
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```
export class LoadingService {
  public isLoading$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() {}

  startLoading(): void {
    this.isLoading$.next(true);
  }

  stopLoading(): void {
    this.isLoading$.next(false);
  }
}
```

the problem with this solution is the loading interceptor/service does not work as expected when handling multiple requests in the same screen. For example, let's say in Home screen I'm making 3 requests to 3 different endpoints, the value of `isLoading$` will become true, then false, then true and so on until the interceptor is done handling all the requests. I'm looking for a way to fix this but I'm not sure of how to approach this, as you can see in the interceptor code above I implemented some logic with a counter but it didn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to show the home screen after finishing all data fetching then you can use forkJoin in your service calls.

Comment: will forkJoin handle all requests as only 1 though? Cause that's my issue with the loading service

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a

Comment: Yes, it will emit values when all the request responses are resolved.

Comment: Yea I solved the issue using forkJoin, I'm still not sure if it's proper solution though because if one of the requests fails I will lose the values from the other requests

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this exact problem before and I used a stack to solve it. In my start loading function I push a value on to the stack located in my loading service. Then in my stop loading I pop the stack. Where ever I am showing my loading icon I check the size of the stack. If its 0 then I know all requests have been sent. If it is greater than 0 I know there are pending requests that have not been completed yet.

Comment: Interesting, I do wonder if this would work, if you look at my code I have a counter but it doesn't solve the issue, and a counter is not different to a stack for this situation.