# Is it possible to define function pre/post processors in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, refactoring

Using angular 8.2.14, I have an angular service doing some http calls through HttpClient. I am using a BehaviourSubject and a related observable to state if the http call has received a response yet. So that my html pages can display a mat-progress-spinner while waiting for the response.

Here is a snippet for my service

```
export class myService {

    private waitingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    readonly waiting$ = this.waitingSubject.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    public call1(): Observable<Whatever1> {
        this.waitingSubject.next(true);
        return this.http.post<Whatever1>('path/to/getWhatever1', null)
          .pipe(finalize(() => this.waitingSubject.next(false)));
    }

    public call2(): Observable<Whatever2> {
        this.waitingSubject.next(true);
        return this.http.post<Whatever2>('path/to/getWhatever2', null)
          .pipe(finalize(() => this.waitingSubject.next(false)));
    }

    public call3(): Observable<Whatever3> {
        this.waitingSubject.next(true);
        return this.http.post<Whatever3>('path/to/getWhatever3', null)
          .pipe(finalize(() => this.waitingSubject.next(false)));
    }
    ...

}
```

The components using this service can then display the spinner using in html pages

```
<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="myService.waiting$ | async" color="primary" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
```

Is there any chances that I can remove 'this.waitingSubject.next(true);' and '.pipe(finalize(() => this.waitingSubject.next(false)))' from my call functions and define somewhere that call1, call2, .., callX must be preprocessed by the next(true) and post processed by the pipe finalize bit ?

This is just a matter of factorization since my code is working as is, but I was not able to find anything related to this idea anywhere.

Thank you by advance

Comment: I like the idea of use an operador to show a loading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078

Comment: Very interesting thread @Eliseo, thank you for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to define a function to set the `waitingSubject`. Try the following

```js
export class myService {
  private waitingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  readonly waiting$ = this.waitingSubject.asObservable();

  private waiter = (call: Observable<any>) => 
    call.pipe(
      tap(_ => this.waitingSubject.next(true)),
      finalize(() => this.waitingSubject.next(false))
    )

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public call1(): Observable<Whatever1> {
    return this.waiter(this.http.post<Whatever1>('path/to/getWhatever1', null));
  }

  public call2(): Observable<Whatever2> {
    return this.waiter(this.http.post<Whatever2>('path/to/getWhatever2', null));
  }

  public call3(): Observable<Whatever3> {
    return this.waiter(this.http.post<Whatever3>('path/to/getWhatever3', null));
  }

  ...
}
```

Note: Untested code, might need to iron out some kinks.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion proposed by Michael D worked after a small change:

His suggested

```
private waiter = (call: Observable<any>) => 
    call.pipe(
      tap(_ => this.waitingSubject.next(true)),
      finalize(() => this.waitingSubject.next(false))
    )
```

was modified to

```
private waiter = (call: Observable<any>) => {
    this.waitingSubject.next(true);
    return call.pipe(
      finalize(() => this.waitingSubject.next(false))
    )
}
```