# how to set loader indicator in http call angular

Tags: angular

when i call my service i want to set the loader to true,and once the load is done i want to false it,here is where i call my service:

```
   this.service.getEventLog(e.turID, dtFrom, dtTo).subscribe(s => {
    this.eventlogs = s;
  });
```

and here is my service:

```
getEventLog(ip,from,to){

 
return this.http.post(this.url_event_log,{},{params:{id: ip,dtFrom: from,dtTo:to}});
 }
```

I have boolean field which according to the value set the loader:

```
  <div *ngIf="loading" class="k-i-loading"></div>
```

but where in my service i should set to true and false?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set like this,

```
getEventLog(){
  this.loading=true;
  this.service.getEventLog(e.turID, dtFrom, dtTo).subscribe(s => {
    this.eventlogs = s;
  }, (err) => {
    this.loading=false;
  }, () => {
    this.loading=false;
  }));
}
```