# how to make custom loading screen in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make a custom loading page in our angular 9 application.

At the moment, we are using `<div [ngClass]="isLoading ? 'loading' : ''>`  item and in each component we have `isloading: boolean` variable.

When there is an api call we set this value to true, and spinning wheel appears and it freezes the app until api finishes the call then we set this value to false and content is visible to user.

I want to make custom loading screen and show some info there. Can someone suggest me any solution for this?

Comment: Make a shared service that calls a single loading component placed in the app component, it can have any param you want

Comment: There is multiple already existing libraries you can use and customize as well like `ngx-spinner`, most of the time you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Do you know any tutorials/source related to this?

Comment: A "good solution" is highly opinion-based and is subjective.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a

Comment: And if you are looking for just "any solution", you can google "angular custom loading spinner" for articles/tutorials, and "angular custom loading spinner github" for samples on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ngx-spinner` library to show a loading spinner when a back end service is made:

example:

when you make the back end call, you have to call this before:

```
this.spinner.show();
```

in the template you can do:

```
<ngx-spinner [fullScreen]="true" type="ball-clip-rotate-multiple" size="medium" bdColor="rgba(32, 55, 77, 0.85)">
  <p class="loading" ><Strong>Please wait ...</Strong></p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

and when the service returns results, you have to do this:

```
this.spinner.hide();
```

Check this demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kruvnm

for more check:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner#stackblitz-demo

Comment: we have like 30-40 components in our application. I assume I need to import ngx-spinner in each component to use this sort of logic and also add the logic?

Comment: You need just to inject the `NgxSpinnerService` in the constructor of the component where you want to use the spinner. and of course import the `NgxSpinnerModule` in your application module.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to inject ngxspinner to each componenet wherever I want to use spinner animation. So, in my case I need to use this at least 20 components, which sounds too much writing the same code. Are there any other way to make this more centralized? or is this how it is? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you can check the documentation: [ngx-spinner](https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner) for now I'm using this component by injecting the service in any component where I use it in my application, so will check but not sure If I can find another way for now, if any I'll comment here.

Answer (score 0):

In my applications I usually have a loading state component (If you're not familiar, there are 5 core types of a UI component you should implement:

- blank state (Content is loaded but empty, i.e. empty list)
- loading state (Content still loading)
- partial state (The view does not have all it's content yet or is working on parts of it. This can also mean a long list that has only on entry and should therefore use other visualization)
- error state (Something went wrong and cannot recover)
- ideal state (Content is available and well-formed)

I usually build my components to cover ideal and partial state and have separate, components for error, loading and blank state. I give them inputs so the context can provide more information. So if you have a project view and it is empty, you provide a sentence like "You have no projects yet" and the empty state component draws it nicely.

You can then use

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading" ><app-loading-state></app-loading-state></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="error" ><app-error-state [reason]="Failed to load"></app-error-state></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading" ><!-- Content of your view here. --></ng-container>
```