# Want to show loading spinner in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have one download button and table that store user data in `user.component.html` file and when user clicks on the download button then it exports all the table's data into an Excel file.

I want to display a loading spinner when the download takes longer than 1.5 seconds to start.

I am using angular 8.

`user.component.html` file:

```html
<div class ="container">
  <button (click)="generateExcel()"> 
     Generate Excel</button>
  <table>
      -----table related data
  <\table>
</div>
```

`user.component.ts` file:

```js
generateExcel() {
  //Excel Title, Header, Data
  const title = 'Car buyers Report';
  const header = ["Year", "Month", "User", "Model"]
  const data = [
    [2007, 1, "jo", "Volkswagen Passat"],
    [2007, 1, "mike ", "Toyota Rav4"],
    [2007, 1, "david", "Toyota Avensis"],
    [2007, 1, "milenda ", "Volkswagen Gol"]
  ];

  //Create workbook and worksheet
  let workbook = new Workbook();
  let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Car Data');

  //Add Row and formatting
  let titleRow = worksheet.addRow([title]);
  titleRow.font = { name: 'Comic Sans MS', family: 4, size: 16, underline: 'double', bold: true }
  worksheet.addRow([]);
  let subTitleRow = worksheet.addRow(['Date : ' + this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'medium')])

  //Add Image
  let logo = workbook.addImage({
    base64: logoFile.logoBase64,
    extension: 'png',
  });

  worksheet.addImage(logo, 'E1:F3');
  worksheet.mergeCells('A1:D2');

  //Blank Row 
  worksheet.addRow([]);

  //Add Header Row
  let headerRow = worksheet.addRow(header);

  // Cell Style : Fill and Border
  headerRow.eachCell((cell, number) => {
    cell.fill = {
      type: 'pattern',
      pattern: 'solid',
      fgColor: { argb: 'FFFFFF00' },
      bgColor: { argb: 'FF0000FF' }
    }
    cell.border = { top: { style: 'thin' }, left: { style: 'thin' }, bottom: { style: 'thin' }, right: { style: 'thin' } }
  })
  // worksheet.addRows(data);

  // Add Data and Conditional Formatting
  data.forEach(d => {
    let row = worksheet.addRow(d);
    let qty = row.getCell(5);
    let color = 'FF99FF99';
    if (+qty.value < 500) {
      color = 'FF9999'
    }

    qty.fill = {
      type: 'pattern',
      pattern: 'solid',
      fgColor: { argb: color }
    };
  });

  worksheet.getColumn(3).width = 30;
  worksheet.getColumn(4).width = 30;
  worksheet.addRow([]);

  //Footer Row
  let footerRow = worksheet.addRow(['This is system generated excel sheet.']);
  footerRow.getCell(1).fill = {
    type: 'pattern',
    pattern: 'solid',
    fgColor: { argb: 'FFCCFFE5' }
  };
  footerRow.getCell(1).border = { top: { style: 'thin' }, left: { style: 'thin' }, bottom: { style: 'thin' }, right: { style: 'thin' } }

  //Merge Cells
  worksheet.mergeCells(`A${footerRow.number}:F${footerRow.number}`);

  //Generate Excel File with given name
  workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data) => {
    let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    fs.saveAs(blob, 'CarData.xlsx');
  })
}
```

Comment: Try this https://medium.com/@prathameshk73/loading-spinner-in-angular-3f1de1dd960f

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your `writeBuffer` call is what takes you the most time.

As `writeBuffer` is asynchronous, you could use rxjs observables which allow you to have more complex behaviors than a classic async/await.

First convert your promise to an observable :

```js
// here you have a promise
const wBufferPromise = workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer(); 

// and here you have an observable, hence the $ char in the variable name 
const wBufferObservable = from(wBufferPromise );
```

You can then probably user `timeoutWith` from RxJS (which i never used so I won't be able to help you here.

Another possible solution would be to call `setTimeout(myFunc,1500)` where `myFunc` sets your spinner visibility if needed.

**Edit** :
Please have a look at Eliseo's comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078