# Multiple mat-table in a single page, each table having it's own loading spinner on network calls

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am facing an issue where i am loading multiple mat-tables (n number of tables) and i want to load a spinner whenever there is a network call for data on a specific table, loader should appear only in that table.

Comment: Please post all relevant code.

Comment: I like the "nil's operator", see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078). You can has so many "loadings$" in your component as tables and so many `<div *ngIf="(loading$ | async)"> as you want`

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is by defining a boolean variable for each table loader and load the spinner whenever there is a network call. Basically like below:

```
In.ts file:

    public table1Loader = false;
    apiCall() {
    this.table1Loader = true;
    // after successful API call make the boolean as false
    }
    
    
In .html file:
    
    <div *ngIf="table1Loader">
      <spinner>
      </spinner>
    </div>
```