# How to use interceptor for both spinner and button transition

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am new to angular interceptors. Now I want to use the best practice of angular interceptors to shows spinners and button transition while making HTTP calls. I have a set of components, which consists of forms and tables. I want to show the spinner while showing something on the table, likewise, I have another component that contains forms and buttons. I want to show button transition or button loading when clicking on the button.

One interceptor to show the entire page loading in a set of components (while showing something) , and button  loading only for the button in a set of components (when save or edit action perform)

Comment: I have worked on similar approach. You can create a service which can show and hide spinners. Then use interceptor to detect whenever an api call is made and display the spinner and hide it after done. Let me know if this is not clear and you need the code

Comment: @sarfrazanwar. thank you for the response. It's clear to me. But I have the use of both spinners to the entire page and button loading or transition only for the button. because I don't wish to work on every component. I am looking for  something like interceptors

Comment: If you're populating the page/component with data that you get asynchronously, you don't need interceptors - ypu can just do something like: `<your-spinner-comp *ngIf="!dataAvailableFlag"><your-spinner-comp>` and, similarly, use `dataAvailableFlag` to display the page/component html content. Same with the button.

Comment: @MishaMashina thanks for the answer.  as per your answer, I need to work on every component right?

Comment: Probably, but depends on the way you structured the project. If one or a few parent pages load potentially several different child components, you can use the flag in the parent template and load the child only when data is ready.

Comment: Really I don't like use httpInterceptor to show a "spinner", I like the Nils' operator, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078)