# rxjs loader with delay

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Have a withDelayedLoader rxjs operator:

If request is fast (<= 500 ms) don't do anything
If request is slow (> 500 ms) we show loading at least 800 ms or until request was completed

I have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7gtjy6?file=index.ts,index.html), though for some reason forkJoin operator doesn't work here.
You can try the code here: https://rxviz.com/examples/custom-operator

```
const withDelayedLoader = (
    showDelay = 500,
    interval = 800
  ) => {
    return function (source$) {
      return source$.pipe(
        switchMap((pending) => {
            const show$ = timer(showDelay).pipe(filter(() => pending),map(() => pending))
            const hide$ = forkJoin([source$, timer(interval)]).pipe(map(() => false));
            
            return merge(show$, hide$);
        }),
      );
    };
  };


const request$ = interval(2000).pipe(
    startWith(-1),
    take(2),
    map((i) => !(i === 0))
)



request$.pipe(withDelayedLoader())
```

for some reason forkJoin is invoked twice. Would be happy if you can advice what I am doing wrong

Usage

```
const loading$ = request$.pipe(withDelayedLoader())
<div class="loader" *ngIf="loading$ | async">Loading...<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that request$ always emits 2 values, and forkJoin was invoked 2 times, so two timers were created and completed. To solve this issue - we can reorganize a code a bit and use take(1) operator

```
const withDelayedLoader = (showDelay = 500, interval = 800) => {
  return function (source$) {
    const show$ = source$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => timer(showDelay).pipe(map(() => true)))
    );
    const hide$ = source$.pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        forkJoin([source$, timer(showDelay + interval)]).pipe(
          take(1),
          map(() => false)
        )
      )
    );
    return source$.pipe(
      switchMap((pending) => merge(show$, hide$)
      )
    );
  };
};
```

Though I finally came up with a bit another solution - [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yswusv?file=index.ts,index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use some like based in nill's operator. See an example about how work in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078). The idea is pass to the operator a `Subject<boolean>`. NOT return it.

If we want we can also pass the min time to show the "loading".

```
export const prepare = <T>(callback: () => void) => {
  return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> =>
      defer(() => {
          callback();
          return source;
      });
};

export const indicate = <T>(indicator: Subject<boolean>,DELAY:number=250) => {
  let alive = true;
  return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> =>
      source.pipe(
          prepare(() =>
              timer(DELAY)
                  .pipe(
                      takeWhile(() => alive),
                      take(1)
                  )
                  .subscribe(() => {
                      indicator.next(true);
                  })
          ),
          finalize(() => {
              alive = false;
              indicator.next(false);
          })
      );
};


loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();
request$.pipe(indicate(this.loading$,2000))
```

And

```
<div *ngIf="(loading$ | async)">
    loading...
</div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-czyb2r?file=src%2Fapp%2Findicate.operator.ts)

Comment: Yep, such approach can also be implemented, many thanks sharing this