# RXJS - Conditional in switchMap operator for first or subsequent execution

Tags: angular, rxjs

My http fetch method in the service has a parameter "showLoadingSpinner". When it's set to false, the HttpContext DISABLE_LOADER_FOR_REQUEST = true will be set.

I want to set the showLoadingSpinner to false for every subsequent call but not for the first one:

```
First Call: show Loading Spinner
Next Calls: Don't show the Loading Spinner
```

Now I need a conditional inside the pipe in my components method, if it's the first service call or not, without creating a additional state variable.

What I don't want to have:

```
isFirstCall = true;

fetchData(): Observable<Bla> {
    return this.reload$.pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.service.fetch(this.isFirstCall),
        tap(() => this.isFirstCall = false)
    );
}
```

What I want to have:

```
fetchData(): Observable<Bla> {
    return this.reload$.pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.service.fetch(<here should be a conditional based on a RXJS operator, if it's the first emission or not>)
    );
}
```

Is there an operator from RXJS which I can use for it?

Comment: [iif](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif)? BTW, why not use a operator like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the index of `switchMap` rxjs operator to know if it is the first emission or not.

```
fetchData(): Observable<Bla> {
    return this.reload$.pipe(
        switchMap((_, index) => this.service.fetch(index)
    );
}
```

Comment: Ohhh it can be so easy! :D I probably would never have thought of that switchMap() has an index.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I see [@tlvi38's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76578894/2398593) and while it'll technically work, it also means that:

- You'll never close the stream
- You'll keep checking from 1 to infinity if something is equal to 0, which is not optimal

Another approach would be to get only the first emission of the reload observable and fetch once. Then close the stream.

If you wish to do that instead, here's how it'd look like:

```js
fetchData(): Observable<Bla> {
    return this.reload$.pipe(
        first(),
        switchMap(() => this.service.fetch())
    );
}
```

Comment: The stream will be closed during the destruction of the component, since I use the async-pipe for the subscription. And the stream should emit multiple times, because everytime the user modifies/deletes an entry "reload$.next()" will be called to trigger a refresh of the provided data.